# Grease Pencil limitations

Tags: animation, grease-pencil, 2d

So I'm wondering if its possible to do similar 3D mixed with 2D animations in blender 2.8, is it possible to do the whole process in blender because of the grease pencil?
Here is an example of what i mean. 
https://youtu.be/Yuk3gZZyNrg

Answer (score 2):

This style is totally possible with a combination of 3d,freestyle render and grease pencil.
The whole process can be done within Blender itself...including the compositing.

Here is a link to "Hero" a Blender and Grease pencil film to give you an idea of some of the possibilities.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKmSdY56VtY

But really...the sky is the limit.

Comment: That's so cool! Honestly blender is amazing